# Bootstrap get panels next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a sort of space between my menu and my other boxes.

The screen will make it clear;

[image: pic]

So as you can see, the menu is larger then the big box on the right, but the second box where stands `Verbanningen die ten einde lopen` must 'stick' to the other panel. So the menu is independant of the second box. Hope you guys understand.

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</strong></div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body thread-row">

                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Laatste reports</strong></div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body thread-row">
                @if(count($reports) > 0)
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Door</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Reden (optioneel)</th>
                                <th>Url</th>
                                <th>Bericht</th>
                                <th>Ontvangen op</th>
                                <th>Actie</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($reports as $report)
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/User-{{ $report->reported_by }}">{{ $report->reported_by }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ $report->type }}</td>
                                <td>{{ ($report->reason != '') ? $report->reason : '/' }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ $report->url }}">{{ strstr($report->url, 'Thread-') }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ $report->content }}</td>
                                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $report->reported_at)->format('d-m-y \o\m H:i') }}</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Verwijder</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                @else
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Er zijn momenteel geen gerapporteerde berichten!</div>
                @endif
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Verbanningen die ten einde lopen</strong></div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body thread-row">

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Gebruikersnaam</th>
                                <th>Reden</th>
                                <th>Duur</th>
                                <th>Verbannen door</th>
                                <th>Actie</th>
                                <th>Actie</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Test-user</td>
                                <td>Het meerdermalen beledigen van een teamlid.</td>
                                <td>1 maand<br><small>(tot 6-11-2015)</small></td>
                                <td>Robin</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> bewerken</span></td>
                                <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> opheven</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't modify anything in the bootstrap files, exept the style, but nothing to the grid.

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: I found the issue, I had still an `col-sm-offset-3` left, so I deleted it, now it does work perfect.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that you essentially have two rows. If you want the two wide components to sit immediately beneath each other, the second `col-sm-9` content needs to be inside the first.

Basically you want the two `panel` elements to be siblings.

Something like the following:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</strong></div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body thread-row">

                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Laatste reports</strong></div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body thread-row">
            @if(count($reports) > 0)
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Door</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Reden (optioneel)</th>
                            <th>Url</th>
                            <th>Bericht</th>
                            <th>Ontvangen op</th>
                            <th>Actie</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($reports as $report)
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/User-{{ $report->reported_by }}">{{ $report->reported_by }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ $report->type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ($report->reason != '') ? $report->reason : '/' }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{ $report->url }}">{{ strstr($report->url, 'Thread-') }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ $report->content }}</td>
                            <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $report->reported_at)->format('d-m-y \o\m H:i') }}</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Verwijder</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            @else
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Er zijn momenteel geen gerapporteerde berichten!</div>
            @endif
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Verbanningen die ten einde lopen</strong></div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body thread-row">

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Gebruikersnaam</th>
                            <th>Reden</th>
                            <th>Duur</th>
                            <th>Verbannen door</th>
                            <th>Actie</th>
                            <th>Actie</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Test-user</td>
                            <td>Het meerdermalen beledigen van een teamlid.</td>
                            <td>1 maand<br><small>(tot 6-11-2015)</small></td>
                            <td>Robin</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> bewerken</span></td>
                            <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> opheven</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second col-..-9 is not necesary because you already have a right column where you can put many panels.

[I solve this on](https://jsfiddle.net/utah8re8/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</strong></div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body thread-row">

                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Laatste reports</strong></div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body thread-row">
                @if(count($reports) > 0)
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Door</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Reden (optioneel)</th>
                                <th>Url</th>
                                <th>Bericht</th>
                                <th>Ontvangen op</th>
                                <th>Actie</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($reports as $report)
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/User-{{ $report->reported_by }}">{{ $report->reported_by }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ $report->type }}</td>
                                <td>{{ ($report->reason != '') ? $report->reason : '/' }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ $report->url }}">{{ strstr($report->url, 'Thread-') }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ $report->content }}</td>
                                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $report->reported_at)->format('d-m-y \o\m H:i') }}</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Verwijder</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                @else
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Er zijn momenteel geen gerapporteerde berichten!</div>
                @endif
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Verbanningen die ten einde lopen</strong></div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body thread-row">

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Gebruikersnaam</th>
                                <th>Reden</th>
                                <th>Duur</th>
                                <th>Verbannen door</th>
                                <th>Actie</th>
                                <th>Actie</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Test-user</td>
                                <td>Het meerdermalen beledigen van een teamlid.</td>
                                <td>1 maand<br><small>(tot 6-11-2015)</small></td>
                                <td>Robin</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> bewerken</span></td>
                                <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> opheven</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```